# copy and paste between 2 worksheets VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a code to copy some values (3 lines from a source sheet ) to a target sheet.
The idea is to copy these data by specifying the Week and the year where the data must be added using a userform.
the data on my source sheet :

[image]

the userform is populated with test values, number of weeks, year:
[image]

The data must be added in the 2nd sheet by specifying the year and the Week number, If I choose 2020 on the Week S6 and Test TT AC1, I'll have:

[image]

So far I have only known how to copy one line from the source sheet, my code is

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim WSSource As Worksheet, WSCible As Worksheet
Dim RngSourceR As Range, RngSourceC As Range, CellSourceR As Range, CellSourceC As Range
Dim RngCibleR As Range, RngCibleC As Range, CellCibleR As Range, CellCibleC As Range
Dim RngCibleCs As Range, CellCibleCs As Range

Dim Bad As Boolean
Dim SR As Integer, SC As Byte
Dim CR As Integer, CC As Byte



If Me.ComboBox_Test.ListIndex = -1 Then Bad = True
If Me.ComboBox_Annee.ListIndex = -1 Then Bad = True
If Me.ComboBox_Semaine.ListIndex = -1 Then Bad = True

If Bad = True Then
MsgBox ("Veuillez chosir tous les elements")
Exit Sub
End If

Set WSSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Feuil2")
Set WSCible = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Feuil1")

Set RngSourceR = WSSource.Range("A2:A" & WSSource.Range("A1000").End(xlUp).Row)
Set RngCibleR = WSCible.Range("A5:A" & WSCible.Range("A1000").End(xlUp).Row)
Set RngCibleC = WSCible.Range("A1:HA1")



For Each CellSourceR In RngSourceR
    If Trim(CellSourceR) = Me.ComboBox_Test Then
        SR = CellSourceR.Row
        
    Exit For
    End If
Next CellSourceR

'For Each CellSourceC In RngSourceC
'    If Trim(CellSourceC) = Me.ComboBox_Semaine Then
'        SC = CellSourceC.Column
'    Exit For
'    End If
'Next CellSourceC

SC = WSSource.Cells(SR, WSSource.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set RngSourceC = WSSource.Range(WSSource.Cells(SR, 2), WSSource.Cells(SR, SC))


For Each CellCibleR In RngCibleR
    If Me.ComboBox_Num_Test.ListIndex = -1 Then
        If Trim(CellCibleR) = Me.ComboBox_Test Then
            CR = CellCibleR.Row
        Exit For
        End If
    Else
        If Trim(CellCibleR) = Me.ComboBox_Test & Me.ComboBox_Num_Test Then
            CR = CellCibleR.Row
        Exit For
        End If
    End If
Next CellCibleR

For Each CellCibleC In RngCibleC
    If CStr(CellCibleC) = Me.ComboBox_Annee Then
    Set RngCibleCs = WSCible.Range(WSCible.Cells(4, CellCibleC.Column), WSCible.Cells(4, CellCibleC.Column + 51))
        For Each CellCibleCs In RngCibleCs
            If Trim(CellCibleCs) = Me.ComboBox_Semaine Then
                CC = CellCibleCs.Column
            Exit For
            End If
        Next CellCibleCs
    End If
Next CellCibleC


WSCible.Cells(CR, CC).Resize(1, RngSourceC.Columns.Count).Value = RngSourceC.Value

End Sub
```

What should I change to copy the 3 lines instead of only the 1st line ?

Comment: I didn't really look at the code, but would assume the 4 in the range should be 6, then you have 3 lines in range.

Comment: @ThomasKoelle I got an error " Application defined or object defined error " on the last line: WSCible.Cells(CR, CC).Resize(1, RngSourceC.Columns.Count).Value = RngSourceC.Value

Comment: Please, when code stops on error, move the cursor over the variables (`CC`, `CR`, `RngSourceC.Columns.Count`) and see which of them is strange... The line, like it is, does not look having a problem.

Comment: @FaneDuru I made the changes suggested by ThomasKoelle replaced the 4 in the range by 6, I got an error on the last line, CR=11, CC=O and RngSourceC.Columns.Count=10.

Comment: Why did you use `Dim CC As Byte` and the same for `CC`. Please, try declare them `As Long`.

Comment: @FaneDuru, I made the changes still cant figure out how to copy the whole block of lines.

Comment: CC=0 is clearly not going to work as there is no column zero.

Comment: Then, see why `CC = 0`... Try running your code line by line, in the code area where `CC` take values (pressing F8 - in VBE...).

Comment: Please, put a Break (F9) on the line `CC = CellCibleCs.Column` and see if the code reachs the line in discussion..

Comment: I suppose it doesn't. If this is the fact, please check what is happening in that area, running the code line by line.

Comment: @FaneDuru please take a look at my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the line

```
Set RngSourceC = WSSource.Range(WSSource.Cells(SR, 2), WSSource.Cells(SR, SC))
```

in

```
Set RngSourceC = WSSource.Range(WSSource.Cells(SR, 2), WSSource.Cells(SR, SC).Offset(2))

'insert here the next line, to check if it returns what you need:
Debug.print RngSourceC.Address:Stop
```

and then, copy the range in this way:

```
WSCible.Cells(CR, CC).Resize(RngSourceC.Rows.count, RngSourceC.Columns.Count).Value = RngSourceC.Value
```

Comment: Made the changes, Always teh same error on the alst line @FaneDuru

Comment: @FaruSZ: But you said that your code works for a single line. Is that understanding correct? Did you solve the `CC = 0` problem? If not, how could it work as you say?

Comment: the CC=0 problem came from changing the 4 in this line to 6 :     Set RngCibleCs = WSCible.Range(WSCible.Cells(4, CellCibleC.Column), WSCible.Cells(4, CellCibleC.Column + 51))

Comment: @FaruSZ: I do not care from where it comes... Does your code works for a single line? If yes, how that problematic line looks right now?

Comment: @FaruSZ:  How that problematic line looks right now? I edited my answer and I made a suggestion to insert a `Debug.Print` line. Did you see it?

Comment: instead of having one line, I have 3 lines now

Comment: @FaruSZ: And is this wrong? What **"3 lines from a source sheet"** from your question does mean?

Comment: Ive just insert Debug.Print line I Always get an error on WSCible.Cells(CR, CC).Resize(RngSourceC.Rows.Count, RngSourceC.Columns.Count).Value = RngSourceC.Value
 the 3 lines are are shown in the second post with pictures ( 1st pic)

Comment: Why do you think I suggested inserting of Db.Pr line? **What does it return when the code stops**?

Comment: it's working finally, :D I commented the debug line to see what it gives me, and the whole block of 3 lines was Added thank you very much

Comment: @FaruSZ: Glad I (finally) could help! But we here, when somebody spends some time to solve our problem and post a solution, vote the code up (if enough notoriety) and most important, tick the left code side check  box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. If somebody else will search for a similar issue, he will know that the code works... :)

Answer (score 0):

@FaneDuru
My code is working fine fro adding one line from the source sheet to the target sheet, I think I shoul make some Editing here:

```
For Each CellSourceR In RngSourceR
    If Trim(CellSourceR) = Me.ComboBox_Test Then
    SR = CellSourceR.Row
      
    Exit For
    End If
Next CellSourceR

SC = WSSource.Cells(SR, WSSource.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set RngSourceC = WSSource.Range(WSSource.Cells(SR, 2), WSSource.Cells(SR, SC))


For Each CellCibleR In RngCibleR
    If Me.ComboBox_Num_Test.ListIndex = -1 Then
        If Trim(CellCibleR) = Me.ComboBox_Test Then
            CR = CellCibleR.Row
        Exit For
        End If
    Else
        If Trim(CellCibleR) = Me.ComboBox_Test & Me.ComboBox_Num_Test Then
            CR = CellCibleR.Row
        Exit For
        End If
    End If
Next CellCibleR
```

To be able to copy 3 lines from the source shett to target sheet as I've explained in the pictires below

Comment: Which is the logic connection between the line you are able to copy and the other two? Are they exactly bellow this one, having the same number of columns? Is it the brown selected area in your picture? If yes, you must build the range to be copied in a different way and also to prepare the size of the area where to be pasted. Try, please, but I cannot post here code to be understood... I will try an answer instead.

Comment: Yes, this is the way. But, you may  be warned by administrators... It is not allowed to use the answers in such a way. **An answer must be an answer**! You cannot play with answers. You only could edit your question and come with some things to clarify the issue. When you modify the question requesting **something else** the rules say that you must post another question. Starting from the existing code and explaining what else do you try to accomplish. I would suggest you to delete all your pseudo answers. You solved your problem, good for you, but in an inappropriate way... :)

Answer (score 0):

@FaneDuru
The lines I want to copy from the source sheet are in yellow ( For test TT AC for example):
[image]

after choosing the week number, the year, the test name from the userform, in the target sheet I should have for example:
Test TT AC, Week S6, year 2020 marked in red
Test TT AC 1, Week S1, year 2020 marked in blue

[image]

Comment: @FaneDuru here what I want to have.

Answer (score 0):

@FaneDuru
Hello,
Is there a way to save the color cells from the source sheet(Picture 1) when copying the data to the target sheet (Picture2)?

[image]

[image]

The whole code

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim WSSource As Worksheet, WSCible As Worksheet
Dim RngSourceR As Range, RngSourceC As Range, CellSourceR As Range, CellSourceC As Range
Dim RngCibleR As Range, RngCibleC As Range, CellCibleR As Range, CellCibleC As Range
Dim RngCibleCs As Range, CellCibleCs As Range

Dim Bad As Boolean
Dim SR As Integer, SC As Long
Dim CR As Integer, CC As Long



If Me.ComboBox_Test.ListIndex = -1 Then Bad = True
If Me.ComboBox_Annee.ListIndex = -1 Then Bad = True
If Me.ComboBox_Semaine.ListIndex = -1 Then Bad = True

If Bad = True Then
MsgBox ("Veuillez chosir tous les elements")
Exit Sub
End If

Set WSSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Donn?es")
Set WSCible = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Synth?se")

Set RngSourceR = WSSource.Range("A1:A" & WSSource.Range("A1000").End(xlUp).Row)
Set RngCibleR = WSCible.Range("A21:A" & WSCible.Range("A1000").End(xlUp).Row)
Set RngCibleC = WSCible.Range("A2:JD2")



For Each CellSourceR In RngSourceR
    If Trim(CellSourceR) = Me.ComboBox_Test Then
    SR = CellSourceR.Row
      
    Exit For
    End If
Next CellSourceR

SC = WSSource.Cells(SR, WSSource.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Set RngSourceC = WSSource.Range(WSSource.Cells(SR, 3), WSSource.Cells(SR, SC).Offset(2))

''insert here the next line, to check if it returns what you need:
'Debug.Print RngSourceC.Address: Stop

'Set RngSourceC = WSSource.Range(WSSource.Cells(SR, 2), WSSource.Cells(SR, SC))

For Each CellCibleR In RngCibleR
    If Me.ComboBox_Num_Test.ListIndex = -1 Then
        If Trim(CellCibleR) = Me.ComboBox_Test Then
            CR = CellCibleR.Row
        Exit For
        End If
    Else

        If Trim(CellCibleR) = Me.ComboBox_Test & Me.ComboBox_Num_Test Then
            CR = CellCibleR.Row
        Exit For
        End If
    End If
Next CellCibleR
'Problem is here cellCibleC is nothing so must edit RngCibleC value
For Each CellCibleC In RngCibleC
    If CStr(CellCibleC) = Me.ComboBox_Annee Then
    Set RngCibleCs = WSCible.Range(WSCible.Cells(11, CellCibleC.Column), WSCible.Cells(11, CellCibleC.Column + 51))
        For Each CellCibleCs In RngCibleCs
            If Trim(CellCibleCs) = Me.ComboBox_Semaine Then
                CC = CellCibleCs.Column
            Exit For
            End If
        Next CellCibleCs
    End If
Next CellCibleC

WSCible.Cells(CR, CC).Resize(RngSourceC.Rows.Count, RngSourceC.Columns.Count).Value = RngSourceC.Value

'WSCible.Cells(CR, CC).Resize(1, RngSourceC.Columns.Count).Value = RngSourceC.Value

End Sub



Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Unload Me
End Sub
```

Comment: Copying an array, only the cells values are copied. You must use range `Copy`... To copy format, too.